# Displaying PostGIS Data with Leafletjs

Tags: javascript, postgresql, yii2, leaflet, postgis

I'm learning GIS with PostGIS and I wanted to try something funny so I downloaded shape files from OSM, imported in PostGres with PostGIS extension and now I want to represent data from PostGIS visually. I have Pulled data with Query

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(geom) FROM "dar-es-salaam_tanzania.land_coast;
```

I got bunch of GeoJSON and wanted to  show them to user. Unfortunately it does not show it. I use Yii2 to write codes that pulls the data. Here is the controller code:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $cmd = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(geom) FROM "dar-es-salaam_tanzania.land_coast";');
    $gjsons = [];
    foreach($cmd->queryAll() as $row)
    {
        $gjsons[] = json_decode($row['st_asgeojson']);
    }
    return $this->render('index', ['geojson'=>json_encode($gjsons)]);
}
```

and in view

```
<?php
/* @var $this yii\web\View */
$this->title = 'Map Application';

$this->registerJs("
    var map = L.map('map').setView([6.8000, 39.2833], 13);
    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href=\http://openstreetmap.org\">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
            '<a href=\"http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/\">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
            'Imagery © <a href=\"http://mapbox.com\">Mapbox</a>',
        id: 'examples.map-20v6611k'
    }).addTo(map);
    var geojsonList = $geojson;
    L.geoJson(geojsonList).addTo(map);


"); 
?>
 <div id="map">
 </div>
```

Is there something that am missing? I'm new to leaflet library and am following their tutorials on their site

***UPDATE***

Here is the HTML Output (stripped Geojson to fit SO) [here](http://pastebin.com/YAgNzHrE) is full source
**Note** that I set Height of the map and I can see a grey box with (+) and (-) signs on it but no map is shown.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>Map Application</title>
    <link href="/tech/maps-app/web/assets/7edc4543/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/tech/maps-app/web/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/tech/maps-app/web/css/map.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/tech/maps-app/web/leafletjs/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>
<body>

    <div class="wrap">
        <div id="map">
        </div> 
    </div>

</script><script src="/tech/maps-app/web/assets/c29e8e0a/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/tech/maps-app/web/assets/f3e1524/yii.js"></script>
<script src="/tech/maps-app/web/leafletjs/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="/tech/maps-app/web/assets/7edc4543/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        var map = L.map('map').setView([6.8000, 39.2833], 13);
        L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            maxZoom: 18,
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href=\http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
                '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
                'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
            id: 'examples.map-20v6611k'
        }).addTo(map);
        var geojsonList = [{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[39.094989013528,-7.2022471828125],[38.638288027056,-7.2022471828125],[38.638288027056,-6.638130390625],[39.094989013528,-6.638130390625],[39.094989013528,-7.2022471828125]]]]}];
        L.geoJson(geojsonList).addTo(map);



    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: updated post. see the details above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't set height container. Set in your css file:

```
#map {
    height: 400px;
}
```

And set zoom. Like that:

```
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {zoom: 10, ...
```

Comment: I forgot to include that. I do set it!

Comment: Sorry for ambiguity. I mean the map height is already set but data isn't displayed. see updated question again

Comment: Set `zoom: 10,`. Like that: `L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {zoom: 10, ...`

Comment: Your zoom is very big. And set `height: 400px;`

Comment: you are right. changing zoom to 10 and height to 400px worked. But it shows a full africa map, I wonder where data comes from. Thats another question though.