# Display Data on Leaflet exclusively with Data from PostGIS

Tags: gis, leaflet, postgis

First of all let me say what this post is not all about. Am not asking about how to use PostGIS and Leaflet. I have that resolved in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29945471/displaying-postgis-data-with-leafletjs).

What I am asking is a bit extension of the linked post. In the linked post when I show a map, it somehow shows data that are not found in PostGIS (Obviously its pulling from the Internet somewhere).

I want to plot data **only** from the database and only that. How do I do this?

Comment: PostGIS and Leaflet won't be querying sources from external locations unless you set them up to. Can you show us a live demo page hosted somewhere where your unwanted data is shown?

Comment: other than tiles from OSM, I don't really have anything external. See a linked post for sources. They are just simple and direct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked code has this segment:

```
    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href=\http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
            '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
            'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
        id: 'examples.map-20v6611k'
    }).addTo(map);
```

This is the tile layer from Mapbox (the first line makes that pretty clear, with the url and the tileLayer method). Remove it and there will no longer be that tile layer in the map.

Comment: May be am confused of the meaning. I thought a tile means different coloring of map polygons and lines. It turns out am wrong!